# How to create and restore backups of the Oracle 10g database by using commanline scripts automatically?

Tags: scripting, oracle10g, backup

I want to automate the periodic backup and restore of the Oracle 10g Database.Please, someone help me immediately.
and please note that I want the task to be performed from the command line scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also a very good kick-starter into RMAN backup/restore: http://www.orafusion.com/art_rman1.htm

Comment: Thank you Juraj the link you provided was also very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Oracle Recovery Manager (aka RMAN) from the command line.

[Here](http://ist.uwaterloo.ca/~baumbach/ORACLE10g/rman.html) is a good link that provides good instruction/tutorial on how to use RMAN and how to setup scripting files in order to do backups easily from the command line.

Comment: And to add, I've found another link too.i.e. [link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/rman.htm) for Oracle10g conceptual stuffs.